# Helpdesk solution which is not form based

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I have been looking into Helpdesk plugins for wordpress, and there seem to be a repeating pattern. All the solutions i have looked at are all based on forms. Meaning, the customers have to fill out forms, that are converted to a ticket.
 I would like a way to create an intuitive visual portal, where the customer can click on pictures to create a support request ticket, is that possible?.

An example: a customer (in this case a home user), has issues with a laptop, sometimes the laptop freezes. The user finds the portal I have build, and is able to click on "support request", click on a picture of a laptop, and is then presented with a page with pictures of all the common errors (eg laptop freezing), edited or created by me, the user can then click on the error, and is then taken to a new page where he/she is prompted to fill out additional info & contact info and click "send".

A live example (not wordpress) https://en.esupport.atea.dk/

Is it possible within the wordpress framework to create something like what I have tried to explain above?

To your knowledge, has a plugin like this already been created for wordpress?

Best Regards
Niels

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible within the wordpress framework to create something like what I have tried to explain above?

yes, but you'll need to build it yourself.  I created something similar for a project once using [contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin and a custom multi-form on a slider using the [multi-slide extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-multislide/).  You can also use the [multi-page approach](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/).

Use [images as radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541614/use-images-instead-of-radio-buttons) to enable visual selections of options.

I used the [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) extension to save the submissions directly into custom posts in the dashboard if you need to keep a track of the help requests.

> To your knowledge, has a plugin like this already been created for wordpress?

not that I am aware of and probably not in a free version.